# Generate a file with CMake and add it as an executable

Tags: cmake

I have a project that generates a shell script at CMake time (with `file(WRITE`. How can I get CMake to treat this shell script as an executable of the project (e.g. have it cleaned up, "rebuild", and also installed)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, take a look at [configure_file()](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command%3aconfigure_file) function, it can do all the work for you. If you can't use it, you should [add_custom_command()](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command%3aadd_custom_command), which would produce your file and then [add_custom_target()](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command%3aadd_custom_target), which should `DEPENDS` on `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/your_produced_file`.

In `add_custom_command()` invokation you can use something like that:

```
COMMAND ${CMAKE_PROGRAM} -P ${CMAKE_SCRIPT_THAT_PRODUCES_YOUR_FILE}
```

Comment: I use `configure_file` to produce the script but have to do some weird copy magic to make it executable and can't find a switch to do so. After that no clean-up is performed on the file.

Comment: Hmm. You may try to `set_directory_proprerties(PROPERTY ADDITIONAL_MAKE_CLEAN_FILES yourfile)`

Comment: I'd consider that a hack and it still wont make the file an install target as far as I understand.

Comment: It's proper way to clean files, that are not fully controlled by CMake, so i don't think that it's a hack. And to make it part of install target use `INSTALL(FILES ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/your_file)`.